# TypeScript Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.' in ionic using local notification

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use local notification in my ionic app so I passed some arguments in my click function, in `this.platform.ready()` I have the following:

```
 this.lnotification.on("click", (notification,status)=>{
    let ttsoptions: TTSOptions = {
        "text": JSON.parse(notification.data).AlarmText,
        "locale": 'en-US',
        "rate": 0.8
    };
    this.tts.speak(ttsoptions)
        .then(()=>{
            console.log("it spoke tts worked");
        })
        .catch((ttserr)=>{
            alert(JSON.stringify(ttserr) +" jp"+JSON.parse(notification.data).AlarmText+" "+ notification.data + "status is"+status+ "didnt speak");
        });
    this.rootPage = "AlarmlistPage";
});
```

This is the line giving the error: `(notification,status)`

What can I do to avoid

> (parameter) notification: any Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.

?

Comment: What line is giving that error? And if you hover over the function that the error is about, what does it say the type is?

Comment: @AlexWayne, this line: (notification,status)

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link to code)](https://tsplay.dev/Nl0RQN), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are not using the `on` method correctly. [According to the documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/local-notifications/#on) it takes a single argument (the `eventName`) and returns an observable, which you can then subscribe to. It does *not* take a second argument as a callback.

That means you will need to change that first line to something like:

```
this.lnotification.on("click").subscribe(/* ... callback here ... */)
```

[Here's a complete example](https://enappd.com/blog/local-notifications-in-ionic-4/69/) of implementing local notifications that you may find useful.

Comment: Nice find! 

Comment: @Alex Wale, Thanks.  I was able to find the solution here https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/latest-update-changed-local-notifications-plugin/127674